# Check optional module availability

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, module

I'm writing a project in C# for Unity that is sort of a framework consisting of several modules, one core module and several optional modules.

In the core module some code needs to check whether one of the optional modules exists to be able to add components related to the optional module. This all happens in editor mode.

I first thought I can achieve this with compiler directives by setting a #define in the class of an optional module and then simply check/exclude the code part in the core module. But that option is suboptimal since it only works when setting those defines in the Visual Studio build properties (I can't demand to do that from users who would buy my framework).

What other methods are there to achieve the requirement of the core module checking whether an optional module is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, it sounds like the design has the coupling going the wrong way with the core module knowing *too much* about optional modules.  The core module shouldn't check for a known list of optional assemblies. Doing so introduces an unwanted coupling from the primary assembly to child assemblies. Isn't it better that the core module be independent of the *"optional modules"*?

> What other methods are there to achieve the requirement of the core module checking whether an optional module is available?

### Plug-in System

Perhaps consider a plug-in system where the "core module" is merely responsible for loading any modules which may be present.  Perhaps the modules are merely .DLLs in a child **Plugins** (or **Modules**) folder.  Each module may have a primary module class that inherits from a known base class or realises a particular `IPlugin` interface.  When loaded, **it is the plugin that adds the appropriate components** not the core module, to the **editor**.

**Benefits**

- Each plug-in is a specialist, it alone adds the components necessary to the editor
- Core module is de-coupled from modules/plugins
- the core module has no knowledge as to the functionality exposed in the plugins.
- No `#define` necessary

I'm not saying you need to introduce Microsoft *MAF* or *MEF*, just a minimal working mechanism to load optional code dynamically based upon the presence of the plugin dll or not.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! The problem is that it's more difficult in reality to get this working perfectly modular with Unity. And I don't want to write too much boiler code that only deals with module management. For now I wrote a simple module manager to that optional modules register. There is a small part of API in it that is used to get or set properties dynamically. For example I need the main camera in a class in the core module but it might be set with an optional module. In that case I need to get the camera and cast it.

Comment: @BadmintonCat No worries.  Happy to have given you ideas if anything.  Have a good day and good luck!